# Unicode File IO in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I want to read an Unicode file (UTF-8) and write it back to another file.

Code I used for reading is,  (As in [Textscreen in Codename One, how to read text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912838/textscreen-in-codename-one-how-to-read-text-file))

```
final String textFile = "/readme.txt";
String text = "";

InputStream in = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(null, textFile);

if (in != null){
    try {
        text = com.codename1.io.Util.readToString(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        text = "Read Error";
    }
}
```

I even tried

```
text = com.codename1.io.Util.readToString(in,"UTF-8");
```

and

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
text = com.codename1.io.Util.readUTF(dis);
```

But I am not Unicode is not getting read.

For writing I am doing,

```
String content = "Some Unicode String";
OutputStream stream = fs.openOutputStream(path + "/" + fileName);
stream.write(content.getBytes());
stream.close();
```

and tried,

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(stream);
dos.writeUTF(content);
```

I observed generated file is ANSI encode.

**Update: Solution**

As per @Shai's reply,

Read:

```
// For text file in package structure
InputStream in = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(null, "/" + textFile);

// For file in file system
InputStream in = fs.openInputStream(textFile);


if (in != null) {
  try {
      text = com.codename1.io.Util.readToString(in, "UTF-8"); // Encoding
      in.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      text = "Read Error";
  }
}
```

Write:

```
OutputStream stream = fs.openOutputStream(textFile);
stream.write(content.getBytes("UTF-8"));
stream.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readToString()` method reads with UTF-8 encoding. If you encoded the file in one of the ASCII/ANSI encoding you need to either fix it for UTF-8 or specify the specific encoding to that method.

`readUT`F from `DataInputStream` is something completely different designed for encoded streams and not for text files. `DataInputStream` in general is not designed for text files in Java, you should be using `Reader`/`InputStreamReader` for that sort of stuff.

`getBytes()` uses the platform specific encoding which is rarely what you want you should use `getBytes(String)`.

Comment: I tried all of these solutions but still when I try to display chinese in a BrowserComponent it looks like garbage, I really thought it might work. But it still doesnt, I tried: out.write(html.getBytes("UTF-8"));

Comment: But is the encoding within the HTML itself set to UTF-8? Did the reading work correctly to begin with?

Comment: Yes, reading works fine, html has the metatag for utf8 if thats what you mean, and I can show it on spanlabel, chinese is fine until I view it in a BrowserComponent on ios.

Comment: Does the device have full Chinese support installed?