# Codename one Unicode/emoji on iOS

Tags: ios, sql, file-io, codenameone

I've been working on an app which includes messaging.
We've noticed that emoji characters are causing some issues.
I've updated the server database to support them, and everything is working fine on Android and the simulator but iOS is failing.
For some reason when you send multiple emojis only some of them arrive.
Our data syncing system packages everything into a tar ball which is then unpacked into storage and read into the database.
I think one of the following points is causing this encoding issue;

- During the network transfer (unlikely since it's a binary file)
- When writing to disk
- When reading from disk
- When writing to SQL
- When reading from SQL

By downloading the container for the app and inspecting the db file I can see it's already been broken by the time it get's there, so I think it's either the file stuff or writing into SQL.

I also attempted the techniques described in this;
[Unicode File IO in Codename One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055196/unicode-file-io-in-codename-one)

Comment: That's great, but without actual code (a [mcve]), we have no falsifiable hypotheses to work off, which is problematic with this many failure points. Look at [ask], and do some debugging on your own to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

At some point along the line encoding breaks. Make sure you don't use any of the problematic methods such as:

- `new String(byte[])`
- `String.toByteArray()`
- `OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream)`
- `InputStreamReader(InputStream)`

There are a few more but all of these can lose encoding. You'll need to narrow this down to the exact method that's failing for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem myself. What fixed it for me was calling the following on iOS before I save the text in sqlite

```
NSData *data = [originalValue dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```